# Search and display results using calendar in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to perform search operation using calendars. I shall select two dates i.e. max_date which shall not be more than the current date but can be less and min_date, these two shall be the days range. The result fields are: in_count, out_count, and dwell_time. The output should sum up all the results of all the days which are between the max_date and min_date. How can I do that? Please help. Is there a need to define a model for this? I am completely clueless.

Currently I am performing search operation using a search bar.

My model :

```
class Result(models.Model):

    in_count   = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    out_count  = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    date_time  = models.DateTimeField()
    time       = models.TimeField()


    def __str__(self):
        return "{},{},{},{}".format(self.in_count, self.out_count, self.date_time, self.time)
```

My views.py

```
class ResultListView(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = Result.objects.all()
        print(self.request.GET)
        query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
        if query is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(
                Q(in_count__icontains=query) | Q(out_count__icontains=query) | Q(date_time__icontains=query) | Q(time__icontains=query))
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResultListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        return context


class ResultDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Result.objects.all()
```

My result_list.html

```
 <div class="card-header">Result on {{ object.date_time}}</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="card-title"><a  href="{% url 'result:result' %}"style="color: white; ">Result of Model</a></h3>
    <p class="card-text"> In Count {{ object.in_count }}</p>

    <p class="card-text">Out Count {{ object.out_count}}</p>
```

Expected result is getting the output in the same form as in result_list.html with the result of all the fields of the days starting from min_date till max_date getting displayed and the min_date and max_date should also be shown in the template. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to filter your `Result` objects to include only the relevant entries and then aggregate the filtered entries. This is all explained in the django documentation which I suggest you go through once. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

In your specific case it will look like this:

```
Result.objects.filter(
    date_time__range=[start_date, end_date]
).aggregate(Sum('in_count'), Sum('out_count'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to django and this is my first project, can you most kindly guide me as to how to use this and where? How can I get the start_date and end_date from the date-time picker and return the result back to the browser?

Comment: One has to start somewhere! I suggest though that before you try to create your own app you go at least through the tutorial as it explains most of the basic concept, like views templates and exactly what you asked above ;-) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: If you are happy with the answer above can you please accept it?

Comment: Actually I wanted to ask how it would take input into start_date and end_date from the date time pickers?

Comment: You can access the request parameters like this `request.POST['choice']` For a practical example look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial04/